# Error while compiling protocol buffer on mac

Tags: c++, python-3.x, protocols, protocol-buffers

I am following the tutorial for protocol buffers and I keep running into different errors while compiling. my addressbook.proto  file is in `/Users/flexmaster411/protobuffer`

`protoc -I=/Users/flexmaster411/protobuffer  --python_out= /Users/flexmaster411/protobuffer/addressbook.proto  /Users/flexmaster411/protobuffer`

I keep getting the following error even though I have syntax = "proto3" on my proto file

`[libprotobuf WARNING google/protobuf/compiler/parser.cc:471] No syntax specified for the proto file. Please use 'syntax = "proto2";' or 'syntax = "proto3";' to specify a syntax version. (Defaulted to proto2 syntax.)`

Not sure if I have correctly done the destination folders set up which is causing this or not Any help appreciated

```
syntax = "proto3";

package tutorial;

message Person {
  string name = 1;
  int32 id = 2;        // Unique ID number for this person.
  string email = 3;

  enum PhoneType {
    MOBILE = 0;
    HOME = 1;
    WORK = 2;
  }

  message PhoneNumber {
    string number = 1;
    PhoneType type = 2;
  }

  repeated PhoneNumber phones = 4;
}

// Our address book file is just one of these.
message AddressBook {
  repeated Person people = 1;
}
```

Comment: are you able to post some minimal .proto code that will reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hi Richard just added the proto file

Comment: Is your problem the space between `--python_out=` and the name?

Comment: That seems to have got rid of the error  but I get a new one saying missing input file now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you reversed the order of the parameters. `/Users/flexmaster411/protobuffer` is your output directory, so it should appear with `--python_out`. Since you specified it second, `protoc` thinks you're telling it that `/Users/flexmaster411/protobuffer` is an *input*. So it's trying to open a *directory* and then parse it as a `.proto` file. Amusingly, `read()` on a directory returns no data, which `protoc` interprets as a perfectly valid `.proto` file that simply doesn't declare anything! But it then gives you a warning because this empty file doesn't have any `syntax` line.

I think what you meant to type is:

```
protoc -I=/Users/flexmaster411/protobuffer --python_out=/Users/flexmaster411/protobuffer /Users/flexmaster411/protobuffer/addressbook.proto
```

Comment: Thanks mate that did the job